# cursor.fechtmany(size=cursor.arraysize) in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, fetch

I want to retrieve the 100 first rows of my Sqlite3 database:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('aktua.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

print('Actual \tCliente \tHistórica')
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Referencias WHERE r_aktua LIKE '%K'").fetchmany(size=100)

for row in cursor:
    print('%s \t%s \t%s' % row)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

My code retrieves all rows of the database (+4000).
I've read [sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany Docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchmany) and [SQLite Python Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this to limit the sql selection:

```
"SELECT * FROM Referencias WHERE r_aktua LIKE '%K' LIMIT 100"
```

Or changue your code to:

```
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Referencias WHERE r_aktua LIKE '%K'").fetchmany(size=100)

for row in rows:
    print('%s \t%s \t%s' % row)
```

Comment: Thanks @klashxx that works, but the .fechtmany(size=) method should work too.

Comment: Hi @Trimax, fetchmany(size=n) will fetch chunks of n rows each call,but you get what you ask for in your sql. All the table in this case

Comment: If I always get the whole table in Cursor object, then the fetchone() or fetchmany() methods don't modify the Cursor object?

Comment: You're rigth @Trimax, the problem there was the multilpe calls on cursor in the for loop , i updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @klashxx for your help.  I now know two manners of do that issue.

Comment: upvoted! how do i use fetchmany if i want to get one group in each round where group size is variable between 1 to 2600 rows